# Is there any Windows 8 speech to text and text to speech API?

Tags: windows-8, speech-recognition

Windows 8 speech to text and text to speech API from Microsoft or third party

Comment: It seems [Windows 8.1 will have text-to-speech APIs](http://justinangel.net/Win81APIs#tts).

Comment: [See my updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17469991/1230188)

Comment: Does anyone have any updates on Windows 8/Win Rt speech to text and text to speech API from Microsoft or third party?

Answer (score 1):

Windows has full API support for [both speech synthesis and recognition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323805%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

However, note that Windows itself only supports speech recognition for a few languages. I do not know if it is easily possible to hook into one of the standard speech recognition engines unless the user has a supported OS language.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 1**

Windows 8.1 has native support of [Text To Speech API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechsynthesis.aspx), here's [MSDN sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=306721) also.

If you prefer Google Text To Speech API here's [MSDN sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Text-to-speech-in-Windows-93e6ded3) of it.

---

[Text-To-Speech with Microsoft Translator Service - CodePlex](https://translatorservice.codeplex.com/releases/view/97104)

[Using Speech Recognition - Applies to Windows 8, Windows RT](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/using-speech-recognition)

Answer (score -1):

There is a text to speech API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb924350.aspx

But I believe the speech to text problem is a lot more difficult and pricey to solve. You'll need some 3rd party solution.

Comment: Windows also has a built in Speech to Text engine.  Try looking up SAPI.

Comment: @rubenvb: I Agree with you. So, can you please tell me some 3rd party API's which are consistent and reliable for Windows 8 apps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @win8.extentia sorry, I have no clue.